# "Undefined Reference to function" but defined in header and linked with library !! Eclipse and Mingw

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, linker-errors

I am trying to build a project with many depencies. For simplying, let's say 2 projects "Mathematics" and "PhysicalProperties which depends on "Mathematics". These projects are build in libraries static and dll. So we need to get libMathematics.a, Mathematics.dll libPhysicalProperties.a and .dll...
So "PhysicalProperties" needs Boost and the libMathematics.a...
I'm working with Eclipse Indigo and the toolchain is MingW 4.5.0.

The build of "Mathematics" works but not the build of "PhysicalProperties" which gave a linker errors : "undefined reference to function..." in "Mathematics"

I check the dependencies but everything is ok, the function is really declared and defined and the library Mathematics is linked. I check also the symbols in the libMathematics.a and found the function that linker didn't find... So if you 've got ideas, i wil be glad to read you ?
Below are the errors when building :

```
//===========================================================================

Building file: ../WaveTools.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\Users\StageTahar\Desktop\Lucid\Common\Includes" -I"C:\Boost/include/Boost-1_49/" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"WaveTools.d" -MT"WaveTools.d" -o "WaveTools.o" "../WaveTools.cpp"
Finished building: ../WaveTools.cpp

Building target: ElectromagneticWave.dll
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -s -L"C:\Users\StageTahar\Desktop\Lucid\Common\Libraries" -L"C:\Boost/lib" -shared -Wl,--out-implib=libElectromagneticWave.a -o "ElectromagneticWave.dll"  ./ElectromagneticWaveImplementation.o ./WaveTools.o   -lMathematics -lboost_wserialization-mgw45-mt-d-1_49
./ElectromagneticWaveImplementation.o: In function `ZNK11JonesVectorIfE12getIntensityEv':
C:\Users\StageTahar\Desktop\Lucid\Engines\ElectromagneticWave\Debug/../WaveDefinitions.h:124: undefined reference to `float norm<float>(ComplexT<float> const&)'

//=========================================================================================
```

Comment: Double check the function prototypes to make sure they are identical.

Comment: It appears to be a template function, so are you sure that this particular instance of that template (with `float`) is present in the library? If the library has only a version with `double` compiled it won't work.

Comment: I've already checked the function and everything is ok.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the libraries. Someone tells me to add to the linker flags this option : Wl, --export-all-symbols   I'll try and tell you.

Comment: Good. It works with the linker options "Wl, --export-all-symbols" Thanks everyone